# Eliminating the computation of the same value twice in a single SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I need to modify the output of a datetime field so that it returns the first day of the week in which that date falls. For example, if the date is 9/2/2016, it should return 8/29/2016 because that's the Monday of that week (I want Monday, not Sunday). However, I also need to convert the timestamp to a different timezone. The result is that I end up having to convert the timezone twice:

```
CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '+05:00') - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '+05:00')) day
```

I can't simply perform the `INTERVAL` calculation on the UTC datetime and then convert the timezone on the result because the timezone conversion may affect the result of the `WEEKDAY` function, e.g. a datetime of `2016-9-5 00:00 UTC` will actually fall on 9/4 for EST, thus causing it to be part of a different week.

Is there a way to avoid having to make two calls to `CONVERT_TZ` in the `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it into a subquery.

```
SELECT converted - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(converted) AS day
FROM (SELECT CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '+05:00') AS converted
      FROM yourTable) AS x
```

Another way is to assign a user variable. To be able to use it twice, put the assignment into the condition part of an `IF()` expression -- that ensures that the assignment will be done before the uses.

```
IF(@converted := CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '+05:00'),
    @converted - INTERVAL(WEEKDAY(@converted) DAY, 
    NULL) AS day
```

Comment: Definitely one way to do it, but this is far less performing than my current query. I suppose if one was already making use of a subquery, this would be a good option.

Comment: Came up with another way to do it using a user-defined variable.

Comment: Interesting. Would you actually recommend this, or should I just stick with what I've got?

Comment: My understanding is that MySQL can detect common sub-expressions like this and only evaluate them once. So if you don't mind writing the function call twice, it shouldn't have a performance impact.